# CPU Switches from Kernel mode to User Mode on X86 : When and How?

Tags: linux-kernel, context-switch

When and how does CPU Switch from  Kernel mode to User Mode On X86 : What exactly does it do? How does it makes this transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iret` does this for example. See the code [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S#L527) (INTERRUPT_RETURN macro)

Comment: Please add the key points to your post so that when the link breaks this answer is still useful. Posts here need to stand on their own, with links as references to supplemental information.

Comment: The link points the latest linux kernel sources, which does not have the mentioned file anymore, can you update it with a specific version?

Answer (score 6):

In x86 protected mode, the current privilege level that the CPU is executing in is controlled by the two least significant bits of the `CS` register (the `RPL` field of the segment selector).

So a switch from kernel mode (`CPL=0)` to user mode (`CPL=3)` is accomplished by replacing a kernel-mode CS value with a user-mode one.  There's many ways to do this, but one typical one is an `IRET` instruction which pops the `EIP`, `CS` and `EFLAGS` registers from the stack.